# Cannot invoke $function with object of type *

Tags: swift

I'm having trouble with a type error that seems to be incorrect. The following code produces the error:
"Cannot invoke baz with argument list of type (f: (A) -> (), g: (String) -> ())" As indicated, the "incorrect" type is the exact type of baz, which is being called.

NB: I pulled out 'succeed' and 'fail' for type clarity, but the same thing happens when using the functions as closures.

```
class Foo<A> {
  ..
  func baz(f: (A) -> (), g: (String) -> ()) {
    .. do some stuff 
  }
  func bar<A, B>(f: (A -> B)) -> Foo<B> {
    func succeed(a: A) -> () {
      .. do some stuff
    }
    func fail(s:String) -> () {
      .. do some stuff
    }
    baz(f: succeed, g: fail)
    .. do some stuff
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your generic parameter `A` declared for function `bar` overrides the generic type declared for class `Foo`, you need to remove it:

```
class Foo<A> {
    func baz(f: (A) -> (), g: (String) -> ()) {}

    func bar<B>(f: (A -> B)) -> Foo<B> {
        func succeed(a: A) -> () {}

        func fail(s:String) -> () {}

        baz(succeed, g: fail)

        return Foo<B>()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's something about your `A` protocol. I changed and created new `F` so it could compile and it works in my playground:

```
protocol F {
}

class Foo<A> {

    func baz(f: (F) -> (), g: (String) -> ()) {
    }
    func bar<A, B>(f: (A -> B)) -> Foo<B> {
        func succeed(a:F) -> () {}
        func fail(s:String) -> () {}
        baz(succeed, g:fail)
        return Foo<B>()
    }
}
```